# JSON Array to Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to parse and display solr facets which are returned in either JSON or Ruby formar:

> Collections: [ "a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, "d", 4, ... ]

into

```
{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}
```

What is the cleanest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i see you want to do is maybe a hash ? {a => "1", b => "2"}  ??

If so, read below:

```
collections = [ "a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, "d", 4]


result = Hash[*collections.flatten]

result prints {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Well now that we know what you actually want, a `hash` ...

```
collections = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, "d", 4]
Hash[*collections]
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}
```

**Original answer**: I may not understand your goal but...

```
collections = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, "d", 4]
collections.each_slice(2).map{ |(x, y)| "#{x} - #{y}" }
# => ["a - 1", "b - 2", "c - 3", "d - 4"]
```